# Strange show/hide behavior in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, knockout.js

I have some some `HTML` fields and tables the problem I'm facing is that in some fields `show()` and `hide()` is working and on some just don't on google chrome.

Example of working code:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="one-col-box" >
            <label>Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="clientNumber" id="clientNumber" data-bind="event: { dblclick: dbClickChange }, value: clientNumber" style="width: 100%">  
            <select name="clientNumberSel" id="clientNumberSel" data-bind="options: result, value: clientNumbersOldVal, optionsCaption: '--- select ---', event: {change: loadPlans }" style="display: none"></select>
            <img id="imgClose" src="/monitring/js/images/close2.png" alt="Close" data-bind="click: hideClientNums" style="display: none;">
    </div>
```

and the `dbClickChange` function - executed when teh input is double clicked:

```
dbClickChange = function(){
                             $('#clientNumberSel').parent().show();
                             $('#clientNumberSel').show();

                             $('#imgClose').show();
                             $('#clientNumber').hide();                         
                           };
```

The above code works perfectly, but this one is not.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one-col-box" >
                <label style="width: 150px">Classification</label>
               <select class="selects" name="creditClassificationSoge" id="creditClassificationSoge" data-bind="value: creditClassificationSoge">               
                    <option>-- Select --</option> 
                    <option data-bind="click: hideClassif">No</option> 
                    <option data-bind="click: showClassif">Yes</option>         
                </select>
            </div>
    <div class="six-col-box">
        <div class="two-col-box" id="descrH" style="display: none;">
            <label>Description </label>
            <input type="text" style="width: 392px;"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the code executed when `yes` or `no` is selected:

```
showClassif = function(){
                       $('#descrH').show();                       
                   };

                   hideClassif = function(){
                       $("#descrH").hide('fast');
                   };
```

I really can't understand what is wrong with my code, the 2 parts in js are the same, I'm going to start crying. Why in some boxes show/hide is working and in some it don't? Maybe I'm missing something small, but I can't spot it.

Comment: The show part seems fine, but are you sure the function is being called? Add a log statement.

Comment: Looking at the data bind from your working example, it appears to be an entirely different syntax ("event:"), so I'd guess that's the issue.

Comment: @Dave The `event` is executing the js script when an event happens - for example mouseOver, mouseOut, double click, etc... Maybe this is the issue, but there is no event `click` :(

Comment: There is a click event. But I think you're binding to it wrong. I'm not familiar with knockout in particular but you seem to have omitted the "event:{" bit in the data-bind syntax. You could try changing that, or just use jquery or native javascript to bind it instead.

Comment: Did you tried with on change of select box, if it is working then problem with you `data-bind` attribute.

Comment: From your question it seems that this is a Chrome-specific issue.Does it work on other browsers?

Comment: Also I can see  differences in the code:                          data-bind="event: { dblclick: dbClickChange } and                       data-bind="click: hideClassif" are not similar. Add event keyword to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a timeout instead. The script is executed at once, so it's showing, and hiding, at the same time.

```
    // Animate Slide
    function showClassif(id){
        var div = $(id);
        div.show();
        var end = setTimeout(function(){
            div.hide('fast');
            clearTimeout(end);
        }, 200); // The delay is 200ms change the 200 to alter this

    });

    showClassif("#showClassif");
```

Comment: The two behaviours are in different functions.

Comment: Edited to define a function to use in any function. His issue is that show, and hide, are called at the same time, making it appear as though nothing happened.

Comment: Oh, now it shows for a second and dissapears... but still wont show in chrome

Comment: Does chrome's console output anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("#clientNumberSel").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $("#clientNumberSel").css("visibility", "visible");
```